# I want to make a new dataframe (maybe using groupby or loc) with all the unique values in one column becoming column names

Tags: dataframe, multiple-columns

```html
mean_tumor_volume_by_drug_and_time.head(20)


for row in mean_tumor_volume_by_drug_and_time.iterrows():
    for i in range(0, len(uni_drugs_list)):
        if row['Drug']==uni_drugs_list[i]:
            mean_tumor_volume_df2[uni_drugs_list[i]]= row['average_tumor_vol']
            mean_tumor_volume_df2['time_point']=row['Timepoint']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTu0k.png)I have a dataframe with three columns, 'Drug', 'Timepoint', and 'average_tumor_vol'. I want to make a new dataframe with each unique drug as a column, Timepoint as an index, and average_tumor_vol as the content of each column for the drug where the Timepoint is equal to the timepoint column and the average_tumor_vol is the content for each column with the drug name.

The resulting dataframe should have columns 'Timepoint', and each of the drug names.  I want to do it efficiently without using any kind of iterrows().

My attempt at solving this used iterrows and now results in an error, "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str".
I am not even sure where to begin without iterrows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3F2I.png)

The code reveals the structure of the dataframe that I already have in the image below. I want to call the new dataframe mean_tumor_volume_df2.
The top of the resulting dataframe should like something like the image below with the drug names as column names. Also I already have a list of all of the unique values in the drug column called uni_drugs_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple pandas command that I did not know existed with some input from others, pivot. This allows me to do what I needed in one line.

```
df2=mean_tumor_volume_by_drug_and_time.pivot(index='Timepoint', columns='Drug', values='average_tumor_vol')
```

While I asked about using groupby or loc, that was because I expected to use some combination of those statements.